# Parsing code files faster

Tags: c++, string, parsing, c++11

I wrote a fairly complex parser for a stack-based language which loads a file into memory and then proceeds by comparing tokens to see if it is recognized as operand or instruction.

Every time I have to parse a new operand/instruction I `std::copy` the memory from the file buffer to a `std::string` and then do a `

```
if(parsed_string.compare("add") == 0) { /* handle multiplication */} 
else if(parsed_string.compare("sub") == 0) { /* handle subtraction */ } 
else { /* This is an operand */ }
```

unfortunately all these copies are making the parsing slow.

How should I handle this to avoid all these copies? I always thought I didn't need a tokenizer since the language itself and the logic is pretty simple.

Edit: I'm adding the code where I get the copies for the various operands and instructions

```
  // This function accounts for 70% of the total time of the program
  std::string Parser::read_as_string(size_t start, size_t end) {

    std::vector<char> file_memory(end - start);
    read_range(start, end - start, file_memory);
    std::string result(file_memory.data(), file_memory.size());
    return std::move(result); // Intended to be consumed
  }

  void Parser::read_range(size_t start, size_t size, std::string& destination) {

    if (destination.size() < size)
      destination.resize(size); // Allocate necessary space

    std::copy(file_in_memory.begin() + start,
      file_in_memory.begin() + start + size,
      destination.begin());
  }
```

Comment: can you show where/how you are creating the copies?

Comment: @NathanOliver Sure, here it is.

Comment: How exactly you checked that copying strings is the most slowest operation?

Comment: `return std::move(anything)` is wrong. Which resource taught you to do that?

Comment: This is why people build FSAs to match lexemes;   if you don't want to use a real lexer generator you can even code it by hand.   Otherwise you are complaining about a solved problem.

Comment: @IraBaxter FSA == Finite State Automata? I'm not getting how a FSA should get in the way with lexers.. could you expand on that please?

Comment: "Get in the way"?  No, *enable* efficient lexing.  The simple answer is that it is easy to build an FSA whose state tracks which of many possible lexemes your lexer might be processing at a point in the input stream, and decides the next state based only on the next character.    This can be as efficient as few machine instructions per character in the input stream, and this is pretty hard to interpret as "Slow".  You need to read standard text books on how to build compilers, where this is explained in great detail.

Comment: You can reuse the same vector and string objects to save some memory allocations.

Answer (score 6):

This copying is not necessary. You can operate on slices.

```
struct StrSlice {
  StrSlice(const std::string& embracingStr, std::size_t startIx, std::size_t length)
  : begin_(/* todo */), end_(/* todo */) // Assign begin_ and end_ here 
  {}

  StrSlice(const char* begin, const char* end)
  : begin_(begin), end_(end) 
  {}
  // Define some more constructors
  // Be careful about implicit conversions
  //...

  //Define lots of comparasion routines with other strings here
  bool operator==(const char* str) const {
    ... 
  }

  bool operator==(const StrSlice& str) const {
    ... 
  } 

  // You can take slice of a slice in O(1) time
  StrSlice subslice(std::size_t startIx, std::size_t length) {
    assert(/* do some range checks here */);
    const char* subsliceBegin = begin_ + startIx;
    const char* subsliceEnd = subsliceBegin + length;
    return StrSlice(subsliceBegin, subsliceEnd); 
  }
private:
  const char* begin_;
  const char* end_;
};
```

I hope you get the idea. Of course, this slice will break after any change in the associated string, expecially memory reallocation. But it seems like your string donesn't change unless you read a new file.

Comment: `std::string_view` is due to appear in C++17 I believe which is built on this principle. In the mean time `boost::string_ref` looks like it may do the trick if you're into boost.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely not just the copying but also the cascade of string comparisons (assuming you have more than the two instructions you showed).

You might try a lookup table (like std::map or std::unordered_map) that converts instructions into an enum type that you switch on.  So instead of:

```
if(parsed_string.compare("add") == 0) { /* handle multiplication */}
else if(parsed_string.compare("sub") == 0) { /* handle subtraction */ }
...
else { /* This is an operand */ }
```

You'd do:

```
const auto it = keywords.find(parsed_string);
if (it != keywords.end()) {
  switch (it->second) {
    case kAdd:  // handle addition
    case kSub:  // handle subtraction
    ...
  }
} else {
  // handle operand
}
```

If there are more than a few keywords, this will result in far fewer string comparisons, at which point the copies may not be that big of a deal. And if they are, this suggestion can be used in conjunction with others that use "slices" or "views" into the actual data to avoid the copy.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

std::string Parser::read_as_string(size_t start, size_t end)
{
   return file_in_memory.substr(start, end);
}

Your "read_as_string" function does nothing more than the standard "substr", except overhead...

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the prefix of of the input steam against constant strings for keywords is simple to code but certainly isn't fast; if you have N keywords, you will do O(N) *string* comparisons.   If the strings have average length, L, you will do O(N*L) *character* comparisons.   And such comparisons will not let you pick up numbers, identifiers or string literals, for which you cannot just compare a constant string.  (And copying the prefix as your example appears to do doesn't help).

What you should consider doing is building a finite-state based machine to implement your lexer.  This is *the* solution used by virtually every production parser/compiler on the planet, because they tend to be very fast.
Really well-designed FSAs will do a single character lookup per character of the input string; that's pretty hard to beat.

You can produce such an FSA by hand,  or your can use a tool.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis for basic background,
and specific list of widely user lexer-generators.